Migrating open text CM Configuration from server to server
Is there any automation program a available that will migrate OPEN TEXT CM config from server to server
CURRENTLY Manually setting configurations in each server is taking time
None didn't know solution
I m looking for help here
Current manual thing takes lot of time
